# Bold the text partially in a text box which popos up on mouseover-D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following D3 code.

```
    var tooltip= d3.select("body").append("div")
                .style("position", "absolute").style("display", "none")

    circ.on("mouseover", function(d){   //circ is a circle
            tooltip.html(d.venue  +"<br/>"  + d.var2 + ", " + d.var3)
                .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 30 ) + 'px')  // Showing the d.count 
                .style('top',  (d3.event.pageY - 30 + 'px')
                .style("font-size","10px")
                .style("padding", "5px")
                .style("display", "block") 
                .style("background", "White")
                .style("color","black")  //font color
```

I want to bold the venue(d.venue) only and need to get in one line and the remaining two variables in the next line of the comment box without bold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
tooltip.html("<b>" + d.venue  +"</b><br/>"  + d.var2 + ", " + d.var3)
```